# R how to generate a plot like below in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Could you please guide how to generate a plot like below (in link).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/
you can use the plotly library here is a simple example :

```
import plotly.express as px
data_canada = px.data.gapminder().query("country == 'Canada'")
fig = px.bar(data_canada, x='year', y='pop')
fig.show()
```